# Проблема с POST запросом на NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, json, post, httpclient

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
{
    static readonly string stagingApiSecretKey = "**********************";
    static readonly string stagingApiKey = "************************";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
    string millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();
    string data = $"client_order_id=123457&order_price=220.0&order_quantity=0.01&order_type=LIMIT&side=SELL&symbol=SPOT_SOL_USDT";       
    string signature = GenerateSignature($"{data}|{millisecondsSinceEpoch}");

    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();

    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;        
    request.RequestUri = new Uri($"https://api.woo.org/v1/order");
    request.Headers.Add("x-api-timestamp", millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", stagingApiKey);
    request.Headers.Add("x-api-signature", signature);               
    request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = _httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    string json = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    
    Console.WriteLine(json);
   
    static string GenerateSignature(string data)
    {
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stagingApiSecretKey);
        var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код для размещения заявки на бирже. Он прекрасно работает в консольке на NET6.0, но в NET Framework 4.8 - проблема. Запрос на биржу уходит, заявка на бирже размещается, но ответ от биржи не приходит. Программа ждет ответ и висит бесконечно. Уже всё перепробовал ничего не получается.
С GET запросами(подобными) проблем нет.
Может кто сталкивался с подобным? Или что посоветуете?

Comment: `.Result;` - прочитайте про правильное использование `async/await`. Вы вешаете UI поток всякими `.Result;`, что вешает ваше приложение. Создайте асинхронный вызов, все `.Result;` уберите, а методы вызывайте через `await`, будет работать как надо. Еще замечу, что `HttpClient` должен создаваться **только один раз** и жить все время работы приложения, а не каждый вызов метода. Ну и также замечу, что вы очень странно отправляете "форму", ибо для этого есть специальные механизмы, которые избавляют от необходимости ручного создания и заполнения `HttpRequestMessage`.

Comment: А нормально через `await` нельзя асинхронные вызовы сделать? Я не помню где появился `async Main`, но мне кажется давно уже.

Comment: На кой вам .NET FW? Нужно, чтобы программа работала на любых Виндах? Как насчёт [self-contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection) или [AOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, А какие есть специальные механизмы для отправки "формы"?

Comment: `FormUrlEncodedContent`